# Get each row selected data in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have 3 days of data, say from Monday to Wednesday

There are 3 columns of data(date, subject are text boxes, level is a drop down)

```
User ID: 100

Date            Subject         Level(each will be a dropdown, 
                                this level data come from another table)

1/1/2015        English         Beginner (Beginner, Intermediate, Advanced)
1/2/2015        Mathematics     Beginner
1/3/2015        Physics         Intermediate
```

If someone comes in for first time, i want to load the levels data from the other table.

If user chooses, say 'Beginner' for 1/1/2015, i need to save that to the table, when the same user selects again 1/1/2015, i need to load the Beginner and not along with rest of the levels.

In the stored table:

```
User ID     Date           Subject     Level (columns)
100         1/1/2015       English     Beginner
```

Levels table

```
Level (column)

Beginner
Intermediate
Advanced
```

This is how i am displaying the data for above condition:

Based on a boolean flag, that is set in client side code - IsDataSavedInDb

Loading the saved level from database, if the data is already saved.

```
<select name="myLevel"  ng-show="IsDataSavedInDb" ng-model="myReponse.Level">
 <option value="{{myReponse.AssignedTo}}" selected="selected">
    {{myReponse.Level}}
 </option>
</select>
```

Loading all levels from database,if the data was never saved, so that user can make a selection:

```
<select id="myLevels" name="myLevels" ng-show="IsDataSavedInDb==false" 
ng-model="myReponse.Level">
     <option value="select">-Select-</option>
     <option ng-repeat="level in Levels" value="{{level.Level}}" >
       {{level.Level}}
    </option>
 </select>
```

Question - Suppose, if the user comes in first time, selects each row a different level and clicks save button? How to i get each row's selected level name and save it?

Please suggest.

Comment: instead of `ng-repeat`, use `ng-options`.

Comment: can you show the snap of your ui and what does myReponse contains

Comment: @Claies - thank you, i tried with that, i am not able to set the default value on the dropdown via ng-options.

Comment: if you mean that you are unable to make `-select-` the first option, that's because it is working with `ng-model`.  since you have `value="select"`, then your `myResponse.Level` would need to equal `select` for it to show that, which it obviously wouldn't.  just omit the `value` on the default, or use `value=""`.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 could you add a jsfiddle or a plnkr to recreate the issue?